# cfzip - issues with zipping all files in a directory

Tags: coldfusion, cfzip

I have to save multiple files in a directory and once thats done, zip them up and make it available for download.

I have my files saved in a directory and I am trying to use cfzip to zip them all in a zip directory, however, I am getting error. Here is my code:

```
  <cfset sFilePath = 'D:\temp\zip\test.zip'>
  <cfset sSourcePath = 'D:\temp\data\'>

  <CFZIP ACTION="zip" FILE="#sFilePath#" SOURCE="#sSourcePath#">
```

It gives me java.io.FileNotFoundException: ensure file is valid zip file (access denied) error. Do we need to set up special permissions or its my code?

Comment: Try a cfdirectory on that source path and dump the results.

Comment: the files show up in source path and I see them via ftp. Its the zip file thats giving me error

Comment: your code has some syntax errors - no trailing single quote and no end angle on the first 2 lines.

Comment: I edited it, it was here but not on my actual code

Comment: Yeah - but I thought I'd mention .. just in case. :) Does your zip file exist? The error is telling you it does not exist. Did you create it?

Comment: Does `sFilePath` point to an existing directory? Does CF has permission to write to that directory?